# Call to undefined method Image::resize()

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am having problem with changing logo image in my admin panel, it was working before but after update it outputs an error. Now I am not sure what happens and here is the error:

```
 Call to undefined method Image::resize() …/system/controllers/settings.php
```

This below is the code from that area:

```
case 'logo-post':
    if($_app_stage == 'Demo'){
        r2(U.'appearance/customize/','e',$_L['disabled_in_demo']);
    }
    $validextentions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);
    $file_name = '';
    if(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")){
        $file_name = 'logo-tmp.png';
    }
    elseif(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")){
        $file_name = 'logo-tmp.jpg';
    }
    elseif(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")){
        $file_name = 'logo-tmp.jpeg';
    }
    elseif(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")){
        $file_name = 'logo-tmp.gif';
    }
    else{

    }
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)//approx. 100kb files can be uploaded
        && in_array($file_extension, $validextentions)){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'storage/system/'. $file_name);
        $image = new Image();
        $image->source_path = 'storage/system/'. $file_name;
        $image->target_path = 'storage/system/logo.png';
       // $image->resize('0','40',ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');
        $image->resize(0,0,ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');

        // now delete the tmp image

        unlink('storage/system/'. $file_name);

       // r2(U.'settings/app','s',$_L['Settings Saved Successfully']);

        r2(U.'appearance/customize/','s',$_L['Settings Saved Successfully']);
    }

    else{

        r2(U.'appearance/customize/','e',$_L['Invalid Logo File']);

    }


    break;
```

Line where the error is happening:

$image->resize(0,0,ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: where/what is your class Image() ?

Comment: Did this work when you used the commented line instead? (`$image->resize('0','40',ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');`)

Comment: It is not work too when using >resize('0','40',ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');)

Comment: Yep, i also try to compare the code above with the old version but it is the same. It making me frustrating so much. Here the code : Image.php, imageLib.php, Img.php 
File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/10rwlemh3qhf4w2/File-Code-Image-Resize.zip

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your helping here, Now i know that the image class has been change to Img as Img.php because of the updating and file image.php is contain other gb with imagelib.php. Now i changed the above code to:

### $Img = new Img(); $Img->source_path = 'storage/system/'. $file_name; $Img->target_path = 'storage/system/logo.png'; // $image->resize('0','40',ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1'); $Img->resize(0,0,ZEBRA_IMAGE_BOXED,'-1');

All problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing here is after update, the function Image::resize() was gone away from your file  …/system/controllers/settings.php

Did you have any backup before update code? Please compare your file before and after the update, you will have the answer in this case.

Comment: Yep, i also try to compare the code above with the old version but it is the same. It making me frustrating so much.
Here the code :
Image.php, imageLib.php, Img.php
File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/10rwlemh3qhf4w2/File-Code-Image-Resize.zip